# Can not see “SQL Server Reporting Services” in PowerBI desktop save as menu

Tags: powerbi-desktop

When I get data from SQL Server Analysis Services database and finished designing report in Power BI desktop, in "Save As" menu, I can not see “SQL Server Reporting Services”.

Can you help me activate this important option?

I use the last version of Power BI desktop.

Thank you